# GWT LayoutPanel doesn't stretch its children in Firefox

Tags: firefox, gwt, layout, cross-browser

GWT 2.5.1, Firefox 26.0. No styles, no inherits.

I'm trying to add one `Widget` to the stack of `LayoutPanel` and expecting it to fill the entire page by default. But In `Firefox` it doesn't work. `TextArea` is not stretched at all, `Button` - only in height, but not width.

[image: layout]

```
package foo.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.*;

public class HW implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        Widget childOne = new TextArea();
        ComplexPanel p = new LayoutPanel();
        p.add(childOne);
        Panel rp = RootLayoutPanel.get();
        rp.add(p);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Web Application Starter Project</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="hw/hw.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

*.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='hw'>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <entry-point class='foo.client.HW'/>
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug (see https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4348) with a known fix/workaround but nobody took the time to submit it as a patch: http://www.gwtproject.org/makinggwtbetter.html